# Can a square matrix be idempotent only sometimes?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given any square matrix $A$, is it possible that $A\vec{x}=A^2\vec{x}$ is only true for certain $\vec{x}$? That is, can a square matrix $A$ be idempotent only sometimes?

Comment: Sure. What if $Ax = 0$? I wouldn't use the word "idempotent" in this context though.

Comment: Then $A(A\vec{x})=A(\vec{0})=\vec{0}$, which is trivial. But does this mean $A\vec{x}=A^2\vec{x}$ is always true when $A\vec{x}=\vec{0}$ i.e. $\vec{x}\in\ker{A}$?

Comment: Yes. It is also true if $Ax=x$. The point is that $Ax=A^2x$ is certainly possible for some vectors $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it can. If the matrix has $1$ as one of its eigenvalues then the corresponding eigenspace satisfies your property.

Moreover, if $A$ is invertible then it's easy to see that this is the only possible subspace with this property.

---

As @Prahlad mentions, it's not a good idea to say that "$A$ is idempotent sometimes" since this is not precisely a property of $A$ as a matrix but as a lienar transformation. It would be better to say something like "$A$ is idempotent on a proper subspace", but I'm not sure this makes sense anyway.